# What documents are needed for a citizen of Botswana travelling to the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, visa-free-entry, botswana

As a citizen of Botswana, I am not required to apply for a visa. However, I would like to know which documents are needed when I arrive in the UK.

Comment: It is true that Botswana nationals are visa-free for the UK, but this is **not a consequence of the Commonwealth of Nations**. There are many Commonwealth nationalities that do need visas, such as India, Pakistan, South Africa, Nigeria, Kenya ...

Answer (score 6):

[gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/botswana/tourism) says:

> You should bring the [same documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) you’d need to apply for a visa, to
>   show to officers at the UK border.

Mainly proof you are going home and your ties back to your home country.